# Cannot convert this pointer from const Class<T> to Class<T>&

Tags: c++, reference, constants, copy-constructor

I am trying to implement a simple copy-constructor:

```
template<typename T>
MyClass<T>::MyClass(const MyClass<T> &other) {
  MyIterator<T> it = other.begin();
  //...
};
```

That single line in the body of the member function generates this error:

> Cannot convert this pointer from const Class to Class&

I tried stuff with const_cast, but it did not work out.

Comment: Show us MyIterator, please

Comment: Its possible that MyIterator is trying to use a non const iterator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `begin` method is apparently non const, and yet you try to call it on a const object.

Comment: Thank you. That was the error. I thought that the const keyword had to be put at the end of the constructor declaration.

Comment: A constructor can't be `const`, as it is creating the object, so modifying it.

Answer (score 0):

And it's a really good thing you can't do that! There are rare cases where you need to use `const_cast`, so in general, like here, it's not the proper thing to do.

`other` is a `const` object, so it's `begin()` should return a const iterator. Instead of

```
MyIterator<T> it = other.begin();
```

use

```
MyConstIterator<T> it = other.begin();
```

And it should work (if you have const iterator defined).